# latex in mintinline but language=python

Tags: minted

First, I want to highlight Python code in latex. Obviously, I can use the command:

```latex
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{python}
|$\omega_x$ = [1,2,3]|
\end{minted}
```

But the command does not apply to inline. Then, the command, `\mintinline`, does apply inline. However, I cannot obtain the Greek alphabet in latex by using the command:

```latex
\mintinline{python}|$\omega_x$ = [1, 2, 3]|
```

The command displays the result `$\omega$ = [1, 2, 3]` in PDF rather than `ω = [1,2,3]`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Would you type `ω` in Python?  If so, try typing that into the minted command.  If not, why are you highlighting it as Python?

Comment: @Teepeemm I just want to match the variable (ω) to a mathematical formula, because it looks like consistency.

Comment: Why not: `\mintinline[escapeinside=||]{python}{|$\omega_x$| = [1, 2, 3]}` ?

Comment: @F.Pantigny I am so sorry. Yesterday, I tried to use the command, but it was error.  However, I just now used the command again, and it is right.